# Accessing variable of the calling class java

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java programming.

My question is:

How can I access a variable in a calling class(a container inside Frame1) from Frame2 or Frame3?

For example: In the following code, I want to display the value in textfield a1(in PanelA nested in Frame1) in Frame2 and the value of textfield a2(in PanelB nested in Frame1) in the frame Frame3.

This is a sample code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class PanelA extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JTextField a1;
    JButton b1;

    PanelA()
    {
        a1=new JTextField("");
        b1=new JButton("Click me");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        add(a1);
        add(b1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==b1){
        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).setVisible(false);
        Frame2 x=new Frame2("Frame2");
        x.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        x.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}

class PanelB extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JTextField a2;
    JButton b2;

    PanelA()
    {
        a2=new JTextField("");
        b2=new JButton("Click me");
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        add(a2);
        add(b2);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).setVisible(false);
        Frame3 x=new Frame3("Frame3");
        x.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        x.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Frame1 extends JFrame
{
    Frame1(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        setLayout(newFlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        PanelA x=new PanelA();
        x.setSize();
        x.setVisible(true);
        PanelB y=new PanelB();
        y.setSize();
        y.setVisible(true);
        JTabbedPane pan1=new JTabbedpane();
        pan1.addTab("A",x);
        pan1.addTab("B",y);
        add(pan1);
    }
}

public class Frame2 extends JFrame
{

}

public class Frame3 extends JFrame
{

}
```

The calling class to Frame1 is something like

```
public class FrameMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame1 x= new Frame1("Frame1");
        x.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        x.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the quick replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own constructor for `Frame2`, like so:

```
public class Frame2 extends JFrame
{
    public Frame2(String textBoxValue)
    {
        //do whatever you want with your textbox value(set it to the textbox (make sure it's initialized at this point!), set it to a local variable)
    }
}
```

And then call this frame like so:

```
Frame2 x = new Frame2("Frame2", a1.getText());
```

You can do thesame thing for `Frame3`.

I do suggest to use clear class/variable names, so it's easier to see what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend you can use the object of that class to access its variable.
Use the keyword public to access globally.
As you wish to get the value of textfield use getText() of class JTextField.

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class test {

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        A aobj=new A();
        B bobj=new B();
        System.out.println(aobj.tf1.getText());
        System.out.println(bobj.tf2.getText());
    }

}


class A
{
    JTextField tf1=new JTextField("one");
}
class B
{
    JTextField tf2=new JTextField("Two");
}
```

The output would be as follows

one

Two

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you,

Frame1

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


 public class Frame1 implements ActionListener{
 JFrame frame;
 JTextField t1;
 JButton btn;
 public PopupExample()
 {
   frame=new JFrame();
   frame.setLayout(null);
   frame.setSize(700,700);
   frame. setLocation(300,10);

   t1=new JTextField();
   t1.setBounds(82,10,100,20);

   frame.add(t1);

   btn=new JButton("SUBMIT");
   btn.setBounds(200,10,100,20);
    btn.addActionListener(this);
   frame.add(btn);


   frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String ar[])

 {
  Frame1 obj=new Frame1 ();

  }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==btn)
    {
        String input=t1.getText();
       Frame2 obj=new Frame2(input);


      }
  }
 }
```

Frame2

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Frame2 {
JFrame frame;
public Frame2(String text)
{
   frame=new JFrame();
   frame.setLayout(null);
   frame.setSize(700,700);
   frame. setLocation(300,10);

   JLabel l1=new JLabel(text);
    l1.setBounds(82,10,100,20);
    frame.add(l1);

   frame.setVisible(true);
 }

  public static void main(String ar[])

{
  Frame2 obj=new Frame2("");

 }

}
```

In this example, value is passing from one class to another via constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are various ways, but a simple way is to implement a method `getTextField()` in your `Frame` class (I would not call it `Frame` and if the Frames have the same functionality, you do not need `Frame1` etc., but you just say `Frame f3 = new Frame()`), or alternatively a `getPanel().getTextField()`. This method returns the `JTextField`, and you can manipulate it, as you like.